# Select element from collection with probability proportional to element value

Tags: algorithm, graph, selection, probability, random

I have a list of vertices, from which I have to pick a random vertex with probability proportional to deg(v), where deg(v) is a vertex degree. The pseudo code for this operation look like that:

```
Select u ∈ L with probability deg(u) / Sigma ∀v∈L deg(v)
```

Where u is the randomly selected vertex, L is the list of vertices and v is a vertex in L. The problem is that I don't understand how to do it. Can someone explain to me, how to get this random vertex. I would greatly appreciate if someone can explain this to me. Pseudo-code will be even more appreciate ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution is to populate a list of size `Sum(d(v))`, for each `v` - you will hold a reference to `v` in **exactly** `d(v)` entries of your list.

Now, select a uniformly distributed variable `x` in range `[0,Sum(d(v)))`, and return `list[x]`

This method requires `O(n^2)` space (since for simple graphs `Sigma(d(v)) is O(n^2)`), and the initialization time is also `O(n^2)`, but it is done only once. Assuming you are going to chose a vertex a lot of times, each time you select it, except the first, will be `O(1)` [assuming `O(1)` randomization function and a random access list].

Answer (score 3):

Another solution; still simple and doesn't require any pre-processing or extra memory (if you have a list of edges in the graph):

Choose a random edge, then choose randomly one of the nodes it connects; that's your random vertex. Probability is proportional to the vertices degree - for every node, the probability is

```
P(v) = sum(P(e: e uses v))/2 = |{e: e uses v}|/(2*|E|) = deg(v)/(2*|E|)
```

Comment: That seems to be the obvious answer. There is no need to create an aux data structure when the edges of the graph contain the same information.

Comment: very clever indeed, IMHO the previous method apply more generally to every situation where you have to select a node proportionally to its value, which can be other than the degree...