# implementing "Select a vertex i with probability p_i "

Tags: networkx

There are `$n$` nodes in a graph. Each node `$i$` has some weight `$p_i$` associated to it. `$\sum p_i = 1$`. I am implementing "Select a vertex i with probability p_i" as given in [[Select element from collection with probability proportional to element value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541831/select-element-from-collection-with-probability-proportional-to-element-value])

I partitioned the `[0,1]` using the `$p_i$`. I randomly pick a number `$r$` between [0,1]. The index `$i$` of `$p_i$` that contains the `$r$` gives the node to be selected.

Is it a correct approach? Please suggest.
thanks

Comment: All relevant information from included links **must** be included **in the text of your question**, such that if the resource becomes unavailable, the question remains valid -- it also makes it *much* easier for fellow users to help. Please read and follow [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include your **[Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.  Then `edit` your question so we can help.

Comment: You can probably use numpy.random.choice()